# Bash test if #- in string but NOT #-# or #-#-#

Tags: bash

I have 5 different references to a file and locations in it, as in;

```
search  | contents
  #-    | some.htm#9-22                             called pat=
 #-#    | some.htm#1-some.htm#3                     called pat2=
#-#-#   | some.htm#21-some.htm#-some.htm#4          called pat3=
   ;    | some.htm#6-some.htm#13;some.htm#22-23     called pat4=
 else   | some.htm#
```

There are some 550 of these references in a csv data file.

The problem I am having is figuring out how to test the variable that contains the reference to see if it contains the search colum listed above.  I do know that it contains special characters.  I have not found a reference to searching for them in a test online.

```
  pat=[#-]
  if [[ $ALIYAH == $pat ]]; then
  SHIR1="$(echo "$ALIYAH" |awk -F \# '{print $1}')"
  START1="$(echo "$ALIYAH" |awk -F \# '{print $2}'|awk -F - '{print $1}')"
  END1="$(echo "$ALIYAH" |awk -F - '{print $2}')"
  return
```

Thanks

So I made the changes recommended below but have no joy.  The test is not matching and so is falling through to the default and not processing as it should.  The debug output

```
+ for ALIYAH in '"${arr[@]:2:11}"'
+ pat='[#-]'
+ [[ some.htm#11-38 == \[\#\-\] ]]
++ echo some.htm#11-38
++ awk -F '#' '{print $1}'
+ SHIR10=some.htm  # this is the fall through, it should fill SHIR1
```

So after some more searching I tried

```
if [[ "$ALIYAH" =~ [#-] ]]; then
```

and that stopped it from falling through

as I feared it is testing positive for patterns 2 and 3 also

Comment: I didn't really want to change the testing order because of how may more of the first there are, so testing it first will eliminate a lot of processing.  Same with second and third.  Forth only having a few and the last type has only one which makes it a good fall through.

Comment: tried if   [[ "$randstring" == [#-] ]]  no joy

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes around the variable name:

```
if [[ "$ALIYAH" == "$pat" ]]; then
...etc...
```

Comment: Seems to have worked, but still need to build the "; then" part

Comment: that's not going to return positive for the next ones is it.  $pat=[#-] for $pat1=[#-#]  because it can't return for that.  Or should I reverse the order of the tests?